# SQL - Grab record with minimum date until cost changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Got a record set where I'm looking to grab the record with the minimum date based on PO until the cost changes.  Any help would be appreciated.  There are around 7 million records and the current cursor just isn't cutting it.

Sample:

```
PO       log_Ts                         cost
123      2012-06-26-10.37.44.035385     2.5896
123      2012-06-27-02.16.14.706817     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.28.57.540731     2.591
123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.948940     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.421713     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-18.34.37.191917     2.5896
123      2012-06-27-02.16.14.705622     2.5896
123      2012-06-27-04.33.18.264742     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.37.44.007667     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.706207     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.26.56.767121     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.919248     2.5896

Looking to grab:
PO       log_Ts                         cost
123      2012-06-26-10.26.56.767121     2.5896
123      2012-06-26-10.28.57.540731     2.591
123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.421713     2.5896
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? (Oracle? MySQL? PostGreSQL? SQL Server?) Different RDBMS have different syntax and capabilities. If you have use of `ROW_NUMBER()` then this can be done using a gaps-and-islands approach.  *[Oh, and please please at least put your sample data in time order...]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with a as
(
  select po, log_ts, cost, row_number() over (partition by po order by log_ts) rn
  from <table>
), b as
(
  select po, log_ts, cost, 1 grp, rn from a where rn = 1
  union all
  select a.po, a.log_ts, a.cost, case when a.cost = b.cost then b.grp else b.grp+1 end, a.rn
  from a
  join b on a.rn = b.rn+1 and a.po = b.po
)
select po, min(log_ts) log_ts, cost 
from b
group by po, cost, grp
```

Comment: Thank you this worked.  Only hang up is the speed was about the same as the cursor (30 minutes for 7 million records).  Pretty new to SQL, is that to be expected with that large of a data set?

Comment: Does your table have an index on `(po, log_ts)`

Comment: Yes it has two indexes, one on PO and one on log_ts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. `SELECT` the rows in the order of log_ts and associate a row number with each row.
2. `SELF JOIN` the result in #1 on firstTable.rownum = secondTable.rownum -1. Each row in the worktable will contain the current and next record.
3. Apply the `WHERE` clause such that the cost value is different and you are interested in the tuple from the second set in the `SELF JOIN`.

E.g.

```
RowNum  PO       log_Ts                         cost    RowNum  PO       log_Ts                         cost
1       123      2012-06-26-10.37.44.035385     2.5896  2       123      2012-06-27-02.16.14.706817     2.5896
2       123      2012-06-27-02.16.14.706817     2.5896  3       123      2012-06-26 10.28.57.540731     2.591
3       123      2012-06-26-10.28.57.540731     2.591   4       123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.948940     2.5896
```

Query:

```
WITH T (PO, Log_Ts, Cost, RowNum) 
AS 
(
SELECT PO, Log_Ts, Cost, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Log_Ts) FROM PO_INFO
) 

SELECT T2.* 
FROM 
    T t1
    JOIN T t2
    ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum - 1 AND t1.cost != t2.cost
```

Result:

```
123      2012-06-26 10.28.57.540731     2.591    2
123      2012-06-26-10.37.43.948940     2.5896   3
```

HTH.

Comment: Please give examples of how you'd create this row number field, and the subsequent query using it.  Otherwise this is onlf a comment (that propegates additional questions that the OP will need to ask) rather than an answer.

Comment: @Dems, Just updated my answer with the query (SQL Server syntax).

Answer (score 0):

This is something that really lends itself to procedural logic (code) rather than set-based logic (sql).  As such I would suggest doing it in code if possible where you can simply sort the data-set and loop through it.

If code is not an option you can do the same thing in a stored procedure using a cursor and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports the LAG() function, it's possible to use the CTE approach in t-clausen.dk's and Vikdor's answers, but without needing a self join.

```
WITH t 
AS 
(
    SELECT PO, log_Ts, Cost, 
    LAG( Cost ) OVER( PARTITION BY PO ORDER BY log_Ts) AS prevcost
    FROM po_log_events
) 
SELECT PO, log_Ts, Cost
FROM t
WHERE prevcost IS NULL 
OR prevcost <> cost       
ORDER BY PO, log_Ts
```

If ROW_NUMBER() and common tables expressions aren't available for your database (i.e., your database is MySQL), the same result can be achieved through correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.PO, p.log_Ts, p.Cost
FROM po_log_events p
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 FROM po_log_events p2 
      WHERE p2.PO = p.PO AND p2.log_Ts < p.log_Ts )
OR NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 FROM po_log_events p3 
      WHERE p3.PO = p.PO 
      AND p3.log_Ts = 
          (SELECT MAX(p4.log_ts) 
           FROM po_log_events p4
           WHERE p4.PO = p.PO
           AND p4.log_Ts < p.log_Ts
           )
      AND p3.Cost = p.Cost
     )
```

The `DISTINCT` can be removed if the table has a unique index on (PO, log_Ts)

Comment: You can't eliminate the self join, what you just did is just the same as writing: select po, min(log_ts), cost from po_log_events group by po, cost

Comment: You're correct. I was expecting the row numbering to reset after each change to cost, while still retaining the chronological sort, but that's not what it's doing.